# unable to inspect c++ variables corresponsing to standard library classes on Eclipse CDT (Luna)

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Just as topic title says, i'm unable to inspect most of the variables corresponding to standard library classes. Eclipse shows either pointer address or tons of errors such as "Multiple errors reported.\ Failed to execute MI command: -var-create - ... Error message from debugger back end: There is no member named xxx."

screenshot: http://i59.tinypic.com/20q02ah.png

Comment: Prolly need to install debug versions of the libraries.